# How to just show hamburger icon of menu not the background bar and have the menu options in top-middle?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a menu as following but I have some issues with it. For example, in full size screen the menu options are not in middle-top of the section that it is located in. Another issue is that I do not know how to remove the black bar when the screen is in cell phone size and the hamburger icon is visible.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/7ahrn8vc/2/)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 search-container">
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>  


        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want remove the hole black navbar with menu or only the background color?

Comment: @Muthukumar just the background color so user would see a hamburger icon once clicked menu options would be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about middle top but the other part should work.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a{
  padding: 10px !important;
} 

.navbar-header {
    background-color: white; //or inherit whatever you like
}


.navbar-toggle.collapsed {
    background-color: black;
}
```

[Completed Demo by Niklas Brunberg](http://jsfiddle.net/7ahrn8vc/7/)

Comment: Thanks, the coloring is great.

Comment: I edited your answer @daniel-newtown, you can see it here where I also added the ability to put the menu options in the middle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ahrn8vc/7/

Comment: @NiklasBrunberg making the changes one by one is not a solution. Your edit modifies considerably Daniel's answer, making it an answer in itself. You should post it as a new answer (giving credit where credit is due), and not as multiple edits to somebody else's answer.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro My edit did not considerably modify Daniel's answer. It kept all of Daniel's code and fixed his bugs only. If I were to make a new answer I would have to copy Daniel's answer and then my answer would be down voted or flagged because it would be just a copy of Daniel's. I would just pollute Stack Overflow if I were to follow your advice. You said my edit was too much, now you don't want a minor edit. Please tell me what size of an edit *you* would  consider acceptable. I am feeling lost at the moment.

Comment: If you think my comments are not appropriate or offensive, flag them for moderator attention. I have nothing else to say about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

for the middle align menu use the css like

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a{
  padding: 10px !important;
}
.navbar-inverse {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  width:100%;
  left: 0
}
```

if you want remove the background color use the css

```
        @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
.navbar-inverse{
  background: transparent;
}
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus{
    background: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle{
    border: 0px none;
  }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background: #666;
}
}
```

this media query is only for mobile screen

Comment: The menu items need to be in the center of the page. Also transparent removes the background of the hamburger as well.

Comment: Daniel's answer for colors is correct, when I make the screen full-size the menu items are not in center-top of the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is will help you

I did menu items to center when display in desktop and then when minimized to cell phone size background bar gets white and then hamburger icon will change to black

link to plunker

**[Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/eqi5UC/preview)**

Answer (score 0):

I already worked quite a bit with bootstrap, so I'm gonna advise that you extend their original style with your own classes instead of just overwriting everthing.
My sugestion is based on flexbox and uses custom classes as a way of making things work as needed.

Check it out, hope it helps. (:

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/ce7L0nez/

CSS:

```
.center-md-content {
    display: flex!important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.center-md-content .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .sm-no-background {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .sm-no-background .navbar-header {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    .sm-no-background .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        background-color: #333;
    }
    .sm-no-background .navbar-toggle {
        border: 0;
    }
    .sm-no-background .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar {
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 search-container">
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                        <p>THIS IS A TEST</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-static-top sm-no-background" role="navigation">
                <div class="container center-md-content">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```